# Do not know how to make count consistent across numbers

Tags: java

I am doing an assignment and need to build a word frequency calculator. The first integer is the total amount of words for the input.

Ex: If the input is:

5 hey Hi Mark hi mark
Expected output is:

hey 1
Hi 2
Mark 2
hi 2
mark 2

My Output is:
hey 1
Hi 1
Mark 1
hi 2
mark 2

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LabProgram {

   public static int getWordFrequency(String[] f, int size, String c){
      int count = 0;
      for (int j = 0; j < f.length; j++) {
          if (f[j] != null && f[j].equalsIgnoreCase(c)) {
              count++;
          }
      }
      return count;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int size = scnr.nextInt();
      String c;
      int i;
      String [] f = new String[size];
      int [] v = new int[size];
      for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          f[i] = scnr.next();
          c = f[i];
          v[i] = getWordFrequency(f, size, c);
      }
      for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
         System.out.println(f[i]+ " " + v[i]);
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: In your current code, getWordFrequency is called *immediately* after each word, you should only call it after all words has been entered.

Comment: Your whole approach is "odd" you read every word into an array and then get the frequency for every word. Since you expect the number of unique words to be less than the total you need to take that into account. An obvious approach would be a map of word->frequency

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am doing an assignment and need to build a word frequency calculator. The first integer is the total amount of words for the input. ..."*

Here is an example.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
Map<String, Integer> m = new TreeMap<>();
for (int i = 0, n = in.nextInt(); i < n; i++)
    m.merge(in.next().toLowerCase(), 1, (a, b) -> ++a);
```

Output

```
5 hey Hi Mark hi mark
{hey=1, hi=2, mark=2}
```

> *"... My Output is: hey 1 Hi 1 Mark 1 hi 2 mark 2 ..."*

The reason this is happening is because you're checking *f* upon each iteration.

Populate *f* fully, and then traverse, and invoke *getWordFrequency*, for each.

```java
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    f[i] = scnr.next();
}
for(i = 0; i < size; i++){
    System.out.println(f[i]+ " " + getWordFrequency(f, size, f[i]));
}
```

Output

```
5 hey Hi Mark hi mark
hey 1
Hi 2
Mark 2
hi 2
mark 2
```

Alternately, you can utilize a *[List](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html)*, and the *[Collections#frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object))* method.

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0, n = in.nextInt(); i < n; i++)
    l.add(in.next().toLowerCase());
for (String s : l)
    System.out.printf("%s %s%n", Collections.frequency(l, s), s);
```

Output

```
5 hey Hi Mark hi mark
1 hey
2 hi
2 mark
2 hi
2 mark
```